# Blender not displaying correct aspect ratio

Tags: rendering

Using HandBrake, I ripped a chapter from a DVD at 720x480 using "strict" anamorphic setting of HandBrake. When I play the rip in VLC it plays at 720x480 aspect ratio. And when I view the properties of the video file it shows as 720x480. And when I add the "movie" to Blender it shows as 720x480 but blender stretches the image vertically, not keeping the aspect ratio. Blender stretches it so that black bars are NOT at the top and the bottom. I have blender set to 720x480 (1:1). Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: "Strict anamorphic settings"? Do you meat to say that you are exporting anamorphic pixels? Then you need to interpret those in blender. 1.2:1, maybe?

Comment: There should be black bars at top and bottom of the video. Blender does not show black bars but instead stretches (distorts) the image, getting rid of the black bars. 1.2:1 just makes the stretch look more distorted. I would need to go below 1 to create black bars at top and bottom.